# How can I use filter in AngularJS based on a reusable "application-scope" JS function?

Tags: angularjs, filter

Using AngularJS, how can I use a Filter (as out of the box feature) to support "String Processing" on "View Level"? knowing that implied JS function (that will implement such string processing) is under a common module & reusable from the whole AngulaJS application (i.e. can be recalled from any view under any module).

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, you may want to share your code.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Injection based on what version of angular you are using.  You should show your code or create a public repo for us to help you.  Here is a shot in the dark!...  You want to create your filters at the app level and inject them into whatever controller you want to use them in.

example:

```
app.filter('upper', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

Then in view1.js do this:

```
.controller('view1', ['$scope','upper', function($scope, upper) {
    var message = 'this is just an example';
}
```

and in your view do something like this:

```
<h1>{{message | upper}}
```

That should display : THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE

Comment: How can I use the same filter in another application?

Comment: U'll need to use injection into the controller.  If you look above, you can see that I create a filter, then I inject it into view1 controller.  Then any view that uses the view1 controller I can use that filter.

Comment: No, I am not asking that. suppose I have two modules called moduleA and moduleB then how can I use same filter in both modules? Here when you define a filter you are doing app.filter, so the module named app will be able to use it. But say if I have another module named app2 that wants to use this filter. Is it still possible to use the same filter in app2?

Comment: Also, can you please answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792017/how-to-filter-on-multiple-values-in-angular-typeahead?noredirect=1#comment64956077_38792017